# Model is either not installed, or is abstract - Django, Python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

when i am migrating the code below i get the following error ----ERRORS:
users.UserStripe.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
users.UserStripe.user: (fields.E307) The field users.UserStripe.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'settings.auth_user_model', but app 'settings' isn't installed.---
I understand that it relates to the fact i have 'user' in the stripe and profile class but I'm not sure how to stop the error. any guidance would be appreciated!

models.py - users

```
import stripe

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


stripe.api_key = '****************' 

class UserStripe(models.Model):
    **user = models.OneToOneField('settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL', on_delete=models.CASCADE)**
    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stripe_id)


class Profile(models.Model):
    **user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)**
    image = models.ImageField(default='', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use <s>`'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'`</s> as a string *literal*, since then Django will look for a model named `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in the `settings` app. But there is no settings app, and nor is there a model with that name.

You should pass the *value* of `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class UserStripe(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stripe_id)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    image = models.ImageField(default='', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).